# Error when creating a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to write an SQL statement to create a stored procedure called Melbourne_KingBed_Hotel_Rooms that lists the names of all the Melbourne hotels  and their room numbers that have a king sized bed– list the results in order of the hotel name and room number. I cant find the error in my statement or where im going wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Melbourne_KingBed_Hotel_Rooms` (BedTypesDesc Varchar(60), City Varchar(45), HotelName Varchar(50), HotelRoomNum Varchar(10))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Melbourne_KingBed_Hotel_Rooms (BedTypes, Cities, Hotels, Rooms) VALUES (BedTypesDesc, City, HotelName, HotelRoomNum);
    WHERE City = Melbourne
    ORDER BY HotelName AND HotelRoomNum;
END
```

Comment: If you are trying to list the names, why are you using `insert`?  Sounds like you should be using `select` instead.  Also, if you are trying to pass those parameters into your `order by` clause, you either should use `dynamic sql` or a `case` statement.  Perhaps sample data and desired results would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: once it has retrieve the list of hotelnames, bedtypes, roomnumbers i just want it order by hotelname first then by roomnumber